# How to setup helm chart to access jenkins through https?

Tags: jenkins, https, kubernetes-helm

I have the below in **values.yaml** for  https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins and it is all fine except I can only access jenkins through http, but not https

```
jenkinsUrlProtocol: "https"
jenkinsUriPrefix: "/jenkins"
ingress:
 enabled: true
 apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
 labels: {}
 annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    path: "/jenkins"
    kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
 hostName: jenkins.xxx.com
 tls:
    - secretName: jenkins.cluster.local
 hosts:
        - jenkins.cluster.local
```

I don't see any errors in the pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this configuration to work, you would need to have an instance of [jetstack/cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager) already configured and running in your cluster. The cert-manager docs have some documentation explaining how to configure [Automatically creating Certificates for Ingress resources](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/issuing-certificates/ingress-shim.html) which you would need to align with the configuration you included already; specifically the annotations for the ingress, and the secret name for starters.

I believe the hostname/hosts you currently have won't be able to have a certificate issued by letsencrypt as they're not using a valid domain.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I received the exactly same issue. Figure out the `secret` has not been created properly even it's defined in `ingress`.

I have a `clusterissuer` created in `cert-manager` namespace previously. As long as the following objects are defined correctly, the both `certificate` and `secret` would be generated

- `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: clusterissuer`
- `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`
- `kubernetes.io/ingress.provider: nginx`

and `tls` part with `secretName`

Here is `ingress` yaml for reference.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: clusterissuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.provider: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: jenkins
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: devops
  creationTimestamp: "2020-11-19T12:49:29Z"
...
  name: jenkins
  namespace: devops
...
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - jenkins.example.com
    secretName: jenkins-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```